# SQL how to create subtotal using JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, union-all

I want to make a query similar to this:

```
Cash x
Inventory x
TOTAL CURRENT ASSET x
PPE x
TOTAL ASSET x
LIST OF LIABILTIES X
LIST OF OWNER'S EQUITY X
TOTAL LIABILITIES AND OWNER'S EQUITY X
```

X= amount

I've managed to get the subtotals and totals using UNION ALL but it gets shown at the very bottom instead of in the middle.

Is there a way to do it with a recursive JOIN? because all the data is only from one table.

This is what I have so far:

```
SQL> SELECT Acctname AS "Account Name", debit, credit
  2  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  3  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 3200
  4  UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 'TOTAL CURRENT ASSETS', SUM(debit) - SUM(credit), null
  6  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  7  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 1040
  8  UNION ALL
  9  SELECT 'TOTAL ASSETS', SUM(debit) - SUM(credit), null
 10  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
 11  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 1131
 12  UNION ALL
 13  SELECT 'TOTAL LIABILITIES AND OE', null, SUM(credit) - SUM(debit)
 14  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
 15  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 2020 AND 3200;
```

The report will come out like this:

```
ACCOUNT NAME                        DEBIT     CREDIT                            
------------------------------ ---------- ----------                            
CASH                                    6                                       
ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE                     1                                       
ALLOWANCE FOR DOUBTFUL ACCTS                       1                            
INVENTORY                               1                                       
SUPPLIES                                1                                       
LAND                                    1                                       
BUILDING                                1                                       
ACCUMULATED DEPR BUILDING                          1                            
MACHINERY                               1                                       
ACCUMULATED DEPR MACHINERY                         1                            
ACCOUNTS PAYABLE                                   1                                                     
WAGES PAYABLE                                      2                            
TAX PAYABLE                                        2                            
NOTES PAYABLE                                      2                            
COMMON STOCK                                       1                            
RETAINED EARNINGS                                  1                            
TOTAL CURRENT ASSETS                    8                                       
TOTAL ASSETS                            9                                       
TOTAL LIABILITIES AND OE                           9
```

Comment: You want a result per line? or all results in one line?

Comment: What is it that "gets shown at the very bottom instead of in the middle"?

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it with your union select statements. You will have to create a pseudo column for the order, like this:

```
SELECT "Account Name", debit, credit FROM
(SELECT Acctname AS "Account Name", debit, credit, 
  CASE WHEN acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 1040 THEN 10
       WHEN acctno BETWEEN 1041 AND 1131 THEN 20
       ELSE 30 END AS acctOrder
  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 3200
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TOTAL CURRENT ASSETS', SUM(debit) - SUM(credit) AS debit, null AS credit, 15 AS acctOrder
  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 1040
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TOTAL ASSETS', SUM(debit) - SUM(credit) AS debit, null AS credit, 25 AS acctOrder
  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 1010 AND 1131
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'TOTAL LIABILITIES AND OE', null AS debit, SUM(credit) - SUM(debit) AS credit, 35 AS acctOrder
  FROM chart_of_accounts_ngo_p
  WHERE acctno BETWEEN 2020 AND 3200)
ORDER BY acctOrder
```